# Update row(s) of a Shiny DataTable while maintaining position

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am creating a Shiny app that displays data.frame information at the top of the screen and specific variable stats at the bottom. The user can navigate the data.frame columns by interacting with a `DT::datatable` object.

When a user clicks on a variable, detailed information is presented that can be edited. I would like this information to be updated and reflected in the datatable. My problem is that when I update the table, it is rendered and shown starting at the very beginning. **How can I preserve the page and row selection of the datatable after making edits?**

Here is a minimal working example that shows the mtcars dataset in a `DT::datatable`. I have some controls that update fields. Notice that datatable is re-rendered back to the first page.

```
library(shiny)

runApp(shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    title = "minimal-working-example",
    fluidRow(
      column(3, inputPanel(
        selectInput("field", "Field", choices = names(mtcars)),
        numericInput("value", "Value", 0),
        actionButton("submit", "Submit")
      )),

      column(9,
        DT::dataTableOutput("table")
      )
    )
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    v <- reactiveValues(mtcars=mtcars)

    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      v$mtcars[input$field] <- input$value
    })

    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(
        v$mtcars,
        selection = "single",
        options = list(pageLength = 5))
    })
  }
))
```

Session Info:

```
Session info --------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (0.99.902)          
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/Chicago             
 date     2016-07-11                  

Packages -------------------------------
 package     * version     date       source                        
 DT            0.1.45      2016-02-09 Github (rstudio/DT@a63e9ac)   
 shiny       * 0.13.0.9000 2016-02-08 Github (rstudio/shiny@e871934)
```

Comment: This is tricky, but doable. Essentially what needs to happen is the current page of the table needs to be saved reactively, which can be done with `Shiny.onInputChange` in javascript. Then when you render the table you callback to open it at the page number it was at before. I'll write up a full answer when I get the chance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be done from inside R without getting into the structure of the `datatable` through JS or something like that.

We utilize the various table state information we get from the `DT` package to render the new updated `datatable` like the one before. Everything we use is discribed in [this `DT` documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html).

Item one: Selection. You can pre-select rows by adding `selected = ...` inside the `selection` argument of the datatable. This can be combined with the variable `input$table_rows_selected` to save the previously selected row and pre-select that exact row on re-rendering.

Item two: Page. The `datatable` package has an option `displayStart` that specifies which row should be shown first when rendering the table. [Documentation here.](https://datatables.net/reference/option/displayStart) So, if you have 5 rows per page, `displayStart = 9` would start the display on page 3. (JavaScript arrays start at 0, so always subtract 1.) This can be combined with `input$table_rows_current` which is a vector of currently visible row numbers. If we store the first entry (minus 1), we know where to start the display.

Full code example below:

```
library(shiny)

runApp(shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    title = "minimal-working-example",
    fluidRow(
      column(3, inputPanel(
        selectInput("field", "Field", choices = names(mtcars)),
        numericInput("value", "Value", 0),
        actionButton("submit", "Submit")
      )),

      column(9,
        DT::dataTableOutput("table")
      )
    )
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    v <- reactiveValues(mtcars=mtcars)
    previousSelection <- NULL
    previousPage <- NULL

    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      previousSelection <<- input$table_rows_selected
      previousPage <<- input$table_rows_current[1] - 1

      v$mtcars[input$field] <- input$value
    })

    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(
        v$mtcars,
        selection = list(mode = "single", target = "row", selected = previousSelection),
        options = list(pageLength = 5, displayStart = previousPage))
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I stumbled across the features in the DT API that you highlight in your solution. I am going to award you the bounty because you answered the question as I posed it. However, in implementing this solution, I discovered that it breaks on sorting the table. Do you have any thoughts on how to address that aspect?

Comment: @Zelazny7 There is the `datatable` option `order`, and you can retrieve the current table order by `input$table_state$order` if you set the `datatable` option `stateSave = TRUE`. But the set is ordered after `displayStart`, so this will result in a false page selection. I would use the ordering to (temporarily) order the dataset and retrieve the actual page the `previousPage` row number will be displayed on (row number after ordering). Then I would use this (modulus page length) as your `previousPage` arg. Plus an exception rule if the ordering column is the one that has been overridden.