# How to preserve selected lines in DT when updating table content?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

This is a follow-up question to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316013/update-rows-of-a-shiny-datatable-while-maintaining-position/38391688#38391688).

I've tried to keep the selected line when updating a filter to a table displayed by `renderDT`:

[image]

NB: the id is the `town` and the table is arranged by the `value` column. I want the selected town to be kept even if the lines are rearranged.

If I change the year the selected line changes in a non consistent way:

[image]

[image]

Here is the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

df <- tribble(~ town     , ~ year  , ~ value,
              "A"        , 2000    ,  80   ,
              "B"        , 2000    ,  90    ,
              "C"        , 2000     , 100    ,
              
              "A"        , 2001    ,  90    ,
              "B"        , 2001    ,  80    ,
              "C"        , 2001    ,  100   ,
              
              "A"        , 2002    ,  90    ,
              "B"        , 2002    ,  100    ,
              "C"        , 2002    ,  80   ,
              )

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  radioButtons(
    inputId = "year",
    label = "Choose a year",
    choices = unique(df$year)
  ),
  
  DTOutput("table", width = "400px"),
  
  h4("Click on first line and then change the year..."),
  
  textOutput("debug"),
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  out <- reactiveVal()
  
  observe(
    out(df |> filter(year == input$year) |> arrange(value))
  )
  
  selection <- NULL
  
  observe({
    selection <<- (out() |> pull(town))[input$table_rows_selected]
    output$debug <- renderText(selection)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT(
    out(),
    options = list(dom = 't', pageLength = 10000, ordering = FALSE),
    selection = list(mode = "multiple",
                     selected =
                       which((df |> arrange(value) |> pull(town)) %in% selection )
                     ),
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(
  launch.browser = TRUE
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option to retain the selected row after switching the year. I made a few changes.

The biggest one being to use an `observeEvent` instead of `observe`. The observeEvent will only 'listen' for when a row(s) is selected and then update the reactiveValues `rv$selection`. Also in the selection option, you were using the entire df to subset down. I modified that to `rv$out`.

I also didn't see `input$col` so I hard coded `value`.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(out = NULL, selection = NULL)
  
  observe({
    rv$out = df |> filter(year == input$year) |> arrange(value)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$table_rows_selected, {
    rv$selection <- (rv$out |> pull(town))[input$table_rows_selected]
    output$debug <- renderText(rv$selection)
  })
  
  # input$col doesn't exist USING "value"
  output$table <- renderDT(
    rv$out,
    options = list(dom = 't', pageLength = 10000, ordering = FALSE),
    selection = list(
      mode = "multiple",
      selected = which((rv$out |> arrange(pick(value)) |> pull(town)) %in% rv$selection),
      target = "row"
    )
  )
}
```